# MD3000i Hot Swap Drives

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, hotswap

Are the drives needing to be hotswappable or does the SAN understand hotswap of any SATA/SAS drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hot-swap any drive that the MD3000i supports.  It's the controller that allows hot swapping, not the disks.

Answer (score 2):

Many SAN controllers will only work with drives that have vendor-specific firmware, and fitting third party drives will almost certainly violate the terms of any support agreement you have with the vendor.  Fibre channel drives (in particular) are quite notorious for this.

In most cases you need to get a drive specifically compatible with that model of SAN.  You may be able to buy such drives 'off the street'.  For example, drives for Clariion SANs are available from many, many vendors, but Clariion controllers will reject drives that do not have specific Clariion firmware.  Many Dell SANs are rebadged Clariions, but I'm not sure OTOH whether this is the case for with MD3000.